# Allow column resize on disabled JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I allow column resize on disabled `JTable`? I have a `JTable` that is sometimes enabled, sometimes disabled to prevent its content being edited. When it's disabled, I'd like to still be able to resize the columns to display all the content of the cell.

I've tried to override `setEnabled` on the table to still disable the table and re-enable the header, but it's not working (the column remain non-resizable).

What can I do?

Comment: The solution is: don't make it disabled. Make it uneditable. You can also prevent the selection change by using a custom SelectionModel.

Comment: resizing only or resizing and reordering together, I think that is possible to dispatch event from mouse_dragged to JTableHeader even Jtable is disabled, better and direct solution is to disable SelectionModel, all methods are in API (row, column, cell), btw Renderer can do that too (isSelected, hasFocus)

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy thanks, making the table model uneditable works fine, the columns are resizable. One side effect though: the mouse cursor doesn't change anymore to indicate that its possible, any idea to get it back.

Comment: @gregseth "the mouse cursor doesn't change anymore to indicate that its possible". What is no longer possible? Mouse cursor is not a resizing cursor?

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy yes, the cursor remains an arrow pointer, and does not change to the icon indicating that the column is resizable.

Comment: @gregseth it's a bug of your code. Please provide a runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) so I can see what's wrong.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy you're right. Good to know: the `JPanel` in which the `JTable` is placed must not be disabled.

Comment: @gregseth nice to help you.